# How to use request module (python 2.7) to crawl .js website?

Tags: python, web-crawler

As I am trying to crawl the real-time stock info from [Taiwan Stock Exchange](http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/group.jsp?ind=TIDX&ex=tse&currPage=0&type=fixed), I used their API to access the desired information. Something strange happened.

For example, I can access the information with the following link [API link](http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/api/getStockInfo.jsp?ex_ch=tse_t00.tw|otc_o00.tw|tse_1101.tw|tse_2330.tw&json=1&delay=0&_=1516681976742) which will return a nice json for me on the browser (something like this: [image]. But it cannot return a json in my program.

My code is the following

```
url = "http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/api/getStockInfo.jsp?ex_ch=tse_t00.tw|otc_o00.tw|tse_1101.tw|tse_2330.tw&json=1&delay=0&_=1516681976742"

print url

def get_data(query_url):

    headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0",
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US'
           #'Accept-Language': 'zh-tw'
          }

    req = requests.session()
    req.get('http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/index.jsp', headers = headers)
    #print req.cookies['JSESSIONID']
    #print req.cookies.get_dict()

    response = req.get(query_url, cookies = req.cookies.get_dict(), headers = headers)

    return  response.text#json.loads(response.text)

a = get_data(query_url = url)
```

And it will simply return u'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n'.

Is there something wrong in my code? Or it is simply not possible to access this kind of web pages with request module?

Or any other suggestions? Thanks a lot!!

ps: Their API is of the format:  http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/api/getStockInfo.jsp?ex_ch=[tickers]&[time]

pps: I try the module selenium and its webDriver. It worked but is very slow. That is why I would like to use request.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the attached image text is non english hence it is printing is ascii value probably. Use utf-8 encoding on the result and you would see the different result.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, Thanks for your suggestion. Actually it can return a pure English json (I updated the image in the post). The problem is that the json can be properly returned as I used a browser, but cannot be fetched by request module. Any more suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will do one thing, I will try to craw it and will let you know if I find anything different.